# How to Select Two Completely Different Data Sets in Same Table?

Tags: mysql

Apologies. Everything I find is crushing my database of a few million records.

Lets say I have table called users, with columns: city,state,email,dogs

And I want to do merge these two queries as one sheet. Normally I do it in PHP and use two queries. Today I want to learn how to SQL properly. But every query crushes my database.

Example,
Q #1

```
SELECT state,count(distinct email),sum(dogs)
FROM users 
GROUP BY state
```

And #2

```
SELECT state,count(distinct email),sum(dogs) 
FROM users
WHERE dogs > 3
GROUP BY state
```

Desired End Result for Report:

```
State,Count of People, People with > 3 dogs
Minnesota,1291,32
Wisconsin,101,5
```

The above is an oversimplification, but hope it produces a useful sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the sum aggregate does not count nulls. You would use a case statement to determine whether a particular record should count:

```
SELECT 
    State, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT 
       CASE WHEN Dogs > 3 THEN Email 
            ELSE NULL 
       END) QtyUsersWithManyDogs, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT Email)  QtyUsers
FROM Users
GROUP BY State
```

This code will result in distinct states and counts of emails where the dogs field is greater than 3. if your table has the dog entries as rows, you would need to write a nested query that results in a total dog count per user.

Comment: So then to also count distinct email, we would just as a
    ... , COUNT(DISTINCT email) after the 'case' ?

Comment: added to the answer, it would just be another aggregation.

Comment: Thanks for quick help! :)